# Customize windows and import data and images using firebase

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, google-maps, firebase-storage

As the title, I want to customize the window and use firebase data import, but I don't know how to load different data for each marker at the same time when the map is imported
I compile using android studio java
This is my own way to load windows and filter data

```
void setinfowindow(String str){
        db.collection("Location")
                .whereEqualTo("title", str)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            LatLng lastLatLng = null;  //設定最後取出的marker為地圖中心點位置

                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {
                                String title = doc.getString("title");
                                String pic= doc.getString("pic");
                                Long bike=doc.getLong("bike");
                                Long parking=doc.getLong("parking");
                                Long id= doc.getLong("id");
                                GeoPoint gps = doc.getGeoPoint("GPS");
                                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowsAdapter(MapsActivity.this,title,gps,pic,bike,parking));
                            }
                        }

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d("Demo", e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
```

This is how I customize the window

```
public class MyInfoWindowsAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
    private final View mWindows;
    private Context mContext;
    private String title,pic;
    private Long bike,parking;
    private GeoPoint gps;
    private StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    public MyInfoWindowsAdapter(Context mContext,String title,GeoPoint gps,String pic,Long bike,Long parking) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.title=title;
        this.gps=gps;
        this.pic=pic;
        this.bike=bike;
        this.parking=parking;
        mWindows= LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.info_windows,null);

    }
    private void rendowWindowText(Marker marker,View view){
        TextView tvTitle=view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        TextView tvBike=view.findViewById(R.id.tvBike);
        TextView tvParking=view.findViewById(R.id.tvParking);
        ImageView iV1=view.findViewById(R.id.iV1);
        ImageView imageView=view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ImageView imageView2=view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        //ConstraintLayout cl1=view.findViewById(R.id.cl1);
       tvTitle.setText(title);
       tvBike.setText(bike.toString());
       tvParking.setText(parking.toString());
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bike);
        imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.parking);
        //Glide.with(mWindows).load(R.drawable.a2).placeholder(R.drawable.a2).into(iV1);
        storageRef.child("imgs_stust").child(pic+".jpg")
                .getDownloadUrl()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                        Glide.with(mContext)
                                .load(uri).placeholder(R.drawable.a2)
                                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                        if (marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                                            marker.hideInfoWindow();
                                            marker.showInfoWindow();
                                        }

                                        return false;
                                    }
                                }).into(iV1);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d("Demo","失敗"+e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override

    public View getInfoWindow(@NonNull Marker marker) {

        rendowWindowText(marker,mWindows);
        return mWindows;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(@NonNull Marker marker) {
        rendowWindowText(marker,mWindows);

        return mWindows;
    }
}
```

This is the method I currently use to display custom windows and add markers, but this will crash and I don't know if there is a better way

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        db.collection("Location")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            LatLng lastLatLng = null;  //設定最後取出的marker為地圖中心點位置
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {
                                String title = doc.getString("title");
                                GeoPoint gps = doc.getGeoPoint("GPS");
                                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude());
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(title));
                                lastLatLng = latLng;

                            }
                            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(lastLatLng).zoom(15).build();
                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition)); //動畫方式移至對應地點

                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    }

                });

        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {
               setinfowindow(marker.getTitle());
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: So what's the problem with the shared code?

Comment: the code  will crash and   Data cannot be switched at any time